# Priscilla = a girl who prefers to stay home: who might this term have been based on?

Tags: expressions, idioms, slang

*From Flappers to Rappers*, a book of American youth slang, records "Priscilla" as a 1920s slang word for a girl who prefers to stay home.

I'm curious to know why the author chose that name. Is there a historical figure named Priscilla who might plausibly be the archetype for a female who doesn't like to venture out?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The name seems to have an actual etymology that fits your question

[Priscilla](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=Priscilla)

> fem. proper name, from Latin, fem. of Priscillus, diminutive of Priscus, from priscus "antique, old-fashioned, old, ancient, primitive, venerable;"

Other names may just get associated with something due to who was given them, viz, "Sharon" being considered a low class British girl (chav)

Comment: +1 Also (and probably just as important, since US slang has never to my knowledge been strongly influenced by classical scholarship), its hypocorism is "Priss" or "Prissy" (compare ["Miss Priss"](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Miss+Priss)) and it also alliterates with "prim".

Answer (score 2):

*Priscilla* is a name from the New Testament. Priscilla and her husband Aquila were among the first generation of Christians. They hosted Christian worship services in their home in Pontus, which is on the Black Sea in what is now Turkey. *Priscilla* has a connotation of "homebody", one who offers generous hospitality.

Reference: 1 Corinthians 16:19 King James Version: *The churches of Asia salute you. Aquila and Priscilla salute you much in the Lord, with the church that is in their house.*

Answer (score 0):

I'd be much more inclined to consider the similarity between Priscilla (often shortened to Prissy) and **prissy** "fussy and excessively respectable".